# How to send a List in select query of IBatis?

Tags: java, postgresql, ibatis

I am using `Java 1.7, IBatis and postgreSQL`

I have a `StudentVO`

```
import java.util.List;
    public class StudentVO {

        private Long studentId;
        private String studentName;
        private List<Long> studentFriendNums;

        //getters and setters
    }
```

My `Function` in postgreSQL is `get_party_details(VARIADIC bigint[])`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_party_details(VARIADIC bigint[])
  RETURNS TABLE(studentid bigint,studentName character varying, amtPaid numeric) AS
$BODY$
     DECLARE
        SQL VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT
             STU.student_id   as "Student ID"
            ,STU.student_name as "Student Name"
            ,STU.amt_paid     as "Amount Paid"

        FROM    STUDENT     STU

            WHERE STU.STUDENT_ID IN ( SELECT $1[I] FROM GENERATE_SUBSCRIPTS($1, 1) G(I));
END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

My Function Returns the following Results:

> select * from get_party_details(101,102,103,104);

```
StudentId  Student Name     Amt Paid
101          JOHN           428000.00
102          SMITH          275405.00
103          JACKSON        109250.00
104          LOVELESS       63200.00
```

My `queries.xml`

```
<select id="get_party_details" parameterType="StudentVO" 
        statementType="PREPARED" resultMap="partyMap">
            select * from get_party_details(#{studentFriendNums})
</select>

    <resultMap type="StudentVO" id="partyMap">
        <result property="studentId"            column="studentid" />
        <result property="studentName"          column="studentname" />
        <result property="amtPaid"              column="amtpaid" />
    </resultMap>
```

If i use the above Select Statement i am getting the below Exception:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property 'studentFriendNums'.  It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType / jdbcType combination specified.
### Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property 'studentFriendNums'.  It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType / jdbcType combination specified.
```

Any help/suggestions ?

**Edit 1:** I Tried a foreach loop as well which didn't get me out of the issue.

```
<select id="get_party_details" parameterType="StudentVO" statementType="PREPARED" resultMap="partyMap">
        select * from get_party_details(
        <foreach item="friends" index="index" collection="studentFriendNums"
            open="(" separator="," close=")">
            #{friends}
        </foreach>
        )
    </select>
```

Exception with `<foreach/>`:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function get_party_details(record) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 15
### The error may exist in com/myblog/queries.xml
### The error may involve com.myblog.StudentDAO.get_party_details-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select * from epc.get_party_details(    (      ?    ,     ?    ,     ?    ,     ?    )    )
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function get_party_details(record) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 15
```

**Edit 2:** My Ibatis version is `3.2.3`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
    <mapper namespace="com.myblog.StudentDTO">

    <select id="get_party_details" parameterType="StudentVO" 
      statementType="PREPARED" resultMap="partyMap">
        select * from get_party_details
     <iterate property="studentFriendNums" conjunction="," open = "(" close = ")">
            #studentFriendNums[]#
     </iterate>
</select>

    <resultMap type="StudentVO" id="partyMap">
        <result property="studentId"            column="studentid" />
        <result property="studentName"          column="studentname" />
        <result property="amtPaid"              column="amtpaid" />
    </resultMap>

</mapper>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a foreach :

```
   <select id="get_party_details" parameterType="StudentVO" 
            statementType="PREPARED" resultMap="partyMap">
                select * from get_party_details
                <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="studentFriendNums"
                    open="(" separator="," close=")">
                #{item}
               </foreach>
    </select>
```

Just saw your first edit, you don't need to open and close bracket before and after the foreach. Parameter open and close do it for you.

Comment: Its my bad! I just over looked it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the **iterate** tag :

```
<select id="get_party_details" parameterType="StudentVO" 
      statementType="PREPARED" resultMap="partyMap">
        select * from get_party_details
     <iterate property="studentFriendNums" conjunction="," open = "(" close = ")">
            #studentFriendNums[]#
     </iterate>
</select>

<resultMap type="StudentVO" id="partyMap">
    <result property="studentId"            column="studentid" />
    <result property="studentName"          column="studentname" />
    <result property="amtPaid"              column="amtpaid" />
</resultMap>
```

Comment: Using Iterate is giving me a Warning as `The content of element type "select" must match "(include|trim|where|set|foreach|choose|if|bind)".`

Comment: Which version of ibatis are you using? Can you send the complete sqlMap file?

Comment: `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
 <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
 <version>3.2.3</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: I guess myBatis has removed the support for <iterate>. I am sorry but you can use <foreach> tag in place of iterate.